# Negar/ocultar acesso aos arquivos que começam com ponto, como .git, .svn, .DS_Store, .yml

Tags: apache, htaccess, segurança, iis, web.config

Por padrão o Apache nega o acesso aos arquivos cujo o nome comecem com `.ht`, como por exemplo `.htaccess`:

```bsh
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Mas noto que muitos arquivos usam o prefixo `.`, como o `.gitignore`. Creio que este arquivo não faça mal algum, ainda sim penso que o uso do ponto no prefixo seja "fortemente" direcionado a arquivos de configurações. Penso que talvez seja interessante negar acesso a estes arquivos em geral fazendo algo como:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On

# Checa se o arquivo existe
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

# Emite status HTTP 403
RewriteRule ^(\.|/\.) - [F,L]
```

No IIS talvez seja algo como:

```xml
<rule name="Redirect to routes" stopProcessing="true">
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <match url="^(\.|/\.)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

> Adicione a checagem de arquivo porque se o arquivo não existir ele deve emitir 404 e não 403.

Isto seria um *"bom uso"*, ou talvez o `.` como prefixo tenha outros usos além de arquivos de configurações?

**Se este** for o caso então trocaria por um "grupo" de tipos de arquivos:

```
(^|/)\.(git|gitignore|yml|svn)$
```

Comment: Em sistemas de arquivo Unix, arquivos que começam por `.` são considerados "ocultos", e não aparecem quando se listam os arquivos de um diretório usando `ls` (é preciso dizer `ls -a` para vê-los). Por isso é comum que arquivos de configuração comecem por ponto, mas não necessariamente todos os arquivos começando por ponto o são por ser de configuração. É claro, tudo isto é ortogonal à questão de se eles devem ser ocultados ou não pelo Apache/IIS; esta é uma decisão "de negócio" para você, e não há argumentos técnicos a favor nem contra.

Comment: Uma dúvida no htaccess, não há a necessidade de escapar o ponto e a barra ? `RewriteRule ^(\.|/\.) - [F,L]`

Comment: @MagicHat a barra é um escape para o o ponto, no caso o ponto sem a *barra invertida* seria como dizer *"match qualquer coisa, incluindo múltiplas linhas"*, o `\.` é como dizer apenas ponto, pois isto é RegEx. **Nota:** a barra normal `/` não tem nada haver com o escape, ele é usado para checar se o PATH esta dentro de uma "pasta", tipo: se achar um arquivo no root `^\.` como: `.git`, se achar um arquivo dentro de uma pasta `foo/bar/.git`

Comment: @Wtrmute é este mesmo a premissa do meu pensando e o porque formulei a pergunta. Obrigado ;)

Comment: Guilherme, esse seria um bom uso sim. Eu sigo a própria [Apache](https://dimmeria.com/hidden-files-apache-best-practices) que diz ser uma boa prática.

Comment: Assim, se você realmente não quer nem que o cara saiba que você tem esses arquivos, lança um 404 mesmo. É assim quero gitlab faz com projetos privados: quem é de fora nem enxerga a possibilidade desses projetos existirem. Isso dá uma camada a mais de segurança, ainda mais se for algo com informações confidenciais, como pode ser o caso dos arquivos internos do diretório `.git`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é justamente esta a minha duvida, eu estava pensando em fazer eles puramente invisiveis, ou seja se criar uma rota no servidor tipo no wikipedia https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess o usuário de um framework web de rotas poderia criar algo como o wikipedia fez, página customizadas :) Obrigado!

Comment: Quer a resposta no ISS ou no Apache? Fiquei confuso.

Comment: @Everson não é ISS é IIS, é o servidor usado pela Microsoft

Comment: @Everson Porque você me deu um downvote? Sério eu te expliquei na boa, não vou negativar suas postagens porque isso não é o ideal, mas realmente eu te expliquei tudo na boa, era a oportunidade de você melhorar, eu nem negativei tua resposta lá, você realmente acha que isso foi necessário?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade não era downvote, e sim Favoritos para ver qual era a resposta correta. Mas tentei alterar e não estou conseguindo até que a pergunta seja editada. Favor, poderia editar qualquer coisa para eu colocar na opção correta?

Comment: Corrigido! Obrigado.

Comment: @Everson Ok, obrigado. Eu vou dar uma olhada no RFC se acho algo sobre o assunto e lhe comunico, talvez vc mesmo consiga formular uma resposta ;) ... eu queria dar a oportunidade de alguém responder sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 4):

Para o caso de servidor de arquivos, é mais confiável bloquear acesso direto aos arquivos/diretórios que começam com o prefixo `.`, por normalmente conter informações de configuração que [podem ser confidenciais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202094/negar-ocultar-acesso-aos-arquivos-que-come%c3%a7am-com-ponto-como-git-svn-ds-st#comment427141_202094), é melhor bloquear por padrão e liberar por `whitelist`. Achei [esse artigo](https://dimmeria.com/hidden-files-apache-best-practices) que trata amplamente sobre suas dúvidas. Excerto desse artigo:

> Disabling hidden files both on the request side and the file serving side should protect you from leaking hidden files, barring other application security holes.

Em tradução livre:

> Desativar arquivos ocultos, tanto no lado da requisição quanto no lado do serviço de arquivos, deve protegê-lo de vazamento de arquivos ocultos, bloqueando outros furos de segurança no aplicativo.

Claro, isso depende muito de como é organizado o seu projeto e o seu `deploy`; se você fizer um `deploy` de extração de zip, e no zip garantir que não terá os arquivos com informações confidenciais (por exemplo, usando um `make package.zip` que vai compactar todos os seus scripts num zip).

Para questão de links que tem como sufixo o `.` mas que não redirecionam para arquivos (como [você mesmo comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202094/negar-ocultar-acesso-aos-arquivos-que-come%c3%a7am-com-ponto-como-git-svn-ds-st#comment427144_202094)), não tem nenhuma restrição. Por exemplo, a [Wikimedia](https://www.wikimedia.org/) é toda escrita em PHP, muitas vezes com `deploy` para rodar no Apache Server e intercepta a URL e interpretar o que precisa ser enviado, não servindo o arquivo diretamente (com exceção de arquivos *uploaded*).

Comment: A resposta esta quase lá, mas entre bloquear e ocultar e a questão de ocultar apenas alguns ou ocultar todos?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tentei falar sobre ocultar todos na parte de `whitelist`, sendo que o padrão seria bloquear. A ideia nessa resposta é mais algo para um bootstrap para uma resposta mais completa

Answer (score 0):

Esta é a solução que tenho usado caso contrario seriam direccionados todos os ficheiros com extensão á direita do `.`
E assim todos os ficheiros começados por `.giti` são direccionados para outro lado.

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
ErrorDocument 404 /pt/404.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.exemplo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
DirectoryIndex index.php       
Redirect permanent /^(.giti*) /index.php
order deny,allow
```

Comment: Obrigado pela tentativa, mas não estou procurando "soluções" de  bloquear, negar, etc, isto tudo eu sei fazer, **a questão** não tem nada haver diretamente com .htaccess, o problema da pergunta é "recomendação", algo tipo RFC (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/), como eu disse quando adicionei a recomenpensa "Por favor evitem respostas muito opinativas."